# jquery datePicker: oracle won't accept other than dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'

Tags: jquery, oracle, datepicker

When i save a date using jquery datepicker into oracle with format other than 'yy-mm-dd' always return today date.
Does anyone know why? is there something  in oracle or jquery that i must know?
many thank...

Comment: check your business logic. i would say that you have reached the catch block and thats retuning todays date.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have a date picker. If you're using the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), you can tell it what the date format is via the [`dateFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) and [`altFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) options.

But it sounds as though you're passing the output of the datepicker straight through to your database layer. Be sure that you're formatting the date correctly for the DB, ideally through a "date" style parameter (not string/varchar) in whatever DB connection layer you're using. In particular, it's important not to just pass the text sent from the client-side into the DB directly; you need to parse or at least validate the date in the mid-tier to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks.

Comment: yes, i mean jQuery ui datepicker, thanks for correction... and i already format the output via dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'

Comment: But that is different from the yy-mm-dd you mentioned that your database accepts.... Typo?

Comment: @luthfi: Okay, then it sounds like a mid-tier problem with how you're passing the date onto Oracle. You haven't mentioned your mid-tier technology, but you want to use whatever that technology uses for parameterized statements and pass a date, not a string, into the statement. For instance, [here's the PHP stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) you'd use, or the [Java stuff](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: yes, i want to change the format to 'dd-mm-yy' but it won't accept and it works when i change format to 'yy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

To format date (of the jQuery UI datepicker) for use in Oracle, please add the following configuration.

```
dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
```